# Show last group in tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I use tabulator, is there any other possibility or a ready-made example of functions to show only the last group?

```
var lastGr = function(value, count, data, group){
    return group(count) > group(count)-1; // Show only the last group
};

var table = new Tabulator("#tables", {
    groupStartOpen:lastGr,
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do you want to show only the last group are you trying to sum all
>   the rows, etc.

If yes then check [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/column-calcs)

If you want to update the table with only last row, you can do

```
table.clearData();

table.addData([{id:1, name:"bob", gender:"male"}, {id:2, name:"Jenny", gender:"female"}], true);
```

pass the last row to add Data Function as in [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/update#alter-add)